# Entity Framework 6 Upsert

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to get a upsert working with Entity Framework. I have the following code that is throwing an error:

```
using (var db = new Entities.DB.DConn())
{
    //...
    foreach (Account account in accounts)
    {
        Entities.DB.Account dlAccount = new Entities.DB.Account();
        dlAccount.GId = dlG.Id;
        dlAccount.AccountName = account.NameAtFI;
        dlAccount.AccountNumber = account.AcctNumber;
        dlAccount.AcctType = account.AcctType;
        dlAccount.AsOfDate = account.DateCreated;
        dlAccount.IsDeleted = false;
        dlAccount.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUniversalTime();

        db.Entry(dlAccount).State = ((dlAccount.GId == dlG.Id) ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Exception:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

Essentially all I want to do is update the record `if dlAccount.GId == dlG.Id` or insert it if it does not exist. The following code achieves what i want without using EntityState:

```
using (var db = new Entities.DB.DConn())
{
    //...
    foreach (Account account in accounts)
    {
        bool isNewRecord = false;
        Entities.DB.Account dlAccount = new Entities.DB.Account();
        Entities.DB.Account exisitngAcct = db.Accounts.Where(x => x.GId == dlG.Id).FirstOrDefault(); //x.GId is NOT ad primary key
        if (exisitngAcct != null)
        {
            dlAccount = exisitngAcct;
            isNewRecord = true;
        }

        dlAccount.GId = dlG.Id;
        dlAccount.AccountName = account.NameAtFI;
        dlAccount.AccountNumber = account.AcctNumber;
        dlAccount.AcctType = account.AcctType;
        dlAccount.AsOfDate = account.DateCreated;
        dlAccount.IsDeleted = false;
        dlAccount.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUniversalTime();

        if (isNewRecord)
        {
            dldb.Accounts.Add(dlAccount);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Can anyone see anything that I'm perhaps doing wrong here? I would really like to get this working and avoid having to use over bloated code like above.

TIA

Comment: You set equal to each other them near the beginning of the shared code so they have the same value, why even bother with a check then? (`dlAccount.GId = dlG.Id;`)

Comment: Did you add the entity to the context so it is tracked...?

Comment: @Igor Those values need to be set in case of a insert. I guess i'm confused as to how to evaluate if the record exists or not.

Comment: @JoePhillips No, what you see is what i have. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I should point out that the logic in the (non-EntityState) example you posted doesnt look like I would expect it to - at least based on my understanding, which may be wrong :)

*Disclaimer - I've hacked this out in a text editor, please excuse any bugs.

If we take this as your requirement:

> Essentially all I want to do is update the record if dlAccount.GId == dlG.Id or insert it if it does not exist.

Then I would expect the non-EntityState version to look like this:

```
using (var db = new Entities.DB.DConn())
{
    //...
    foreach (Account account in accounts)
    {
        Entities.DB.Account dlAccount = null;

        Entities.DB.Account exisitngAcct = db.Accounts.Where(x => x.GId == dlG.Id).FirstOrDefault(); //x.GId is NOT ad primary key
        if (exisitngAcct != null)
        {
            //If there is an EXISTING account, it will already be tracked by EF so no need to attach it.
            dlAccount = exisitngAcct;                
        }
        else
        {
            //No account exists, so we need to create one, and ADD it to our EF context as a new Entity 
            dlAccount = new Entities.DB.Account();
            db.Accounts.Add(dlAccount);
        }

        dlAccount.GId = dlG.Id;
        dlAccount.AccountName = account.NameAtFI;
        dlAccount.AccountNumber = account.AcctNumber;
        dlAccount.AcctType = account.AcctType;
        dlAccount.AsOfDate = account.DateCreated;
        dlAccount.IsDeleted = false;
        dlAccount.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUniversalTime();

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Assuming the above is what you need, and also assuming that we have a good reason not to just use EF tracking as above, then manually handling EF state would look something like this:

```
using (var db = new Entities.DB.DConn())
{
    //...
    foreach (Account account in accounts)
    {
        Entities.DB.Account exisitngAcct = db.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GId == dlG.Id).FirstOrDefault(); //x.GId is NOT ad primary key

        //NB. Since we're already pulling up the record with EF, there is *probably* no measurable advantage in not just using EF tracking at this point (unless this is a HUUUGE list of objects)
        //    in which case we should use the .AsNoTracking() modifier when we load the records (and they should be loaded in batches/all at once, to reduce DB hits)

        Entities.DB.Account dlAccount = new Entities.DB.Account();
        if(exisitngAcct == null)
        {
            db.Entry(dlAccount).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            dlAccount.Id = exisitngAcct.Id; //We have to set the PK, so that EF knows which object to update
            db.Entry(dlAccount).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        dlAccount.GId = dlG.Id;
        dlAccount.AccountName = account.NameAtFI;
        dlAccount.AccountNumber = account.AcctNumber;
        dlAccount.AcctType = account.AcctType;
        dlAccount.AsOfDate = account.DateCreated;
        dlAccount.IsDeleted = false;
        dlAccount.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow.ToUniversalTime();

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the reply. In a insert scenario obviously these are values i need to have set so that they are inserted into the DB. In a update scenario i need to determine if any record with these values already set exists, and if it does, update the records with the set values. What are you checking with (dlAccount.GId > 0) ? Are you assuming dlAccount.GId to be the primary key?

Comment: Yes I was - the assumption being that if the key == 0 then it is a new record. If GId _isnt_ the PK then substitute that for GId...

Comment: GId is not the primary key, rather just a value i need to key off of when trying to determine if the record exists. Exactly if i had to do this: Entities.DB.Account exisitngAcct = db.Accounts.Where(x => x.GId == dlG.Id).FirstOrDefault();
if (exisitngAcct != null)
{
// Update the records
}else{//insert the record}

Comment: Also, even if it were a primary key, i am not seeing how EF knows if it has found a matching records or not. How does it determine that in your example?

Comment: How does EF know? If you save a record with a non-default PK and EntityState = Modified then EF will assume it exists (and will fail if it does not)

Comment: The code above will create/update correctly if you substitute your Primary Key for GId (although you will need to set it when you are updating a record, based on whatever business logic your data model prescribes)

Comment: My apologies Steve, i'm just not understanding your answer. Is there any way you could revise it within the context of my question and example code. If i can't get this working today i'll probably resort to simply doing a select of the record and update if exists, but i would like to avoid having to resort to this.

Comment: @Nugs hope I've understood your requirement correctly, good luck!

Comment: Steve that makes way more sense now!!! Almost all examples i have looked at for EnityState do not show that you actually still have to do a lookup of the record PK id. This was throwing me off, hence my questions about how EF knows. Thank you for bearing with my on this and clearing the haze.

Comment: No problem at all. Glad to help!

Comment: All I'm hearing is "diy, ef6 has no Upsert" :)

Comment: Pretty much @Rodney - but really its "diy, MSSQL has no upsert" ;)

Comment: Point taken, @Steve Land. I'm just assuming EF was created in the first place to allow MSSQL to be what it's not and just whining that they didn't keep layering process-expensive "helpers" to save me a couple of keystrokes...which I will undoubtedly revert during code optimization a couple of years later ;)